# @Counter-style rules in html

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I am aware of the css counter functions but recently I came across **@counter-style** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-counter-styles-3/, which we can use to define custom rules for counters.

I tried locally to see the effect of counter-style but browser is not honoring counter-style properties.

HTML ex

```
<style>
@counter-style thumbs {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: "\1F44D";
  suffix: " ";
}

ul {
  list-style: thumbs;
}
</style>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Browser renders content in the normal way only, i can see the bullets only.
Is it not supported by all the browsers?
Can any one give me working same for @counter-style.

Comment: Very few browsers actually implement this: https://caniuse.com/#search=Counter-style. Basically, it doesn’t exist yet.

Comment: It is still not supported by most of the browsers. Alternative is to use background-image for `li` element with padding.

Comment: or easily consider pseudo elemnt

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't understand your comment. Pseudo element mostly has content with (counter, attr  etc ) but we can define custom rule for counter in pseudo elements